# Program won't run after I input in drJava

Tags: drjava

I'm fairly new to programming and am having trouble with a program I came up with. It's a guessing game, the user has to guess a random number generated and you have 6 chances. Unfortunately I don't quite understand what is wrong with the program. Every time I try to input "Yes" to start the program, nothing happens. Listed below is the code please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Project4{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Would you like to play a game? (Yes or No)");
    String a1 = input.next().toLowerCase();
    while(a1.equals("Yes")){
               Random secretnum = new Random();
      int num;
      for(int counter=0; counter<2; counter++){
        num = 1+secretnum.nextInt(99);  
      System.out.println("You have 6 chances to guess the secret number");
        System.out.println("Player : guess a number between 1 and 100");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        while(num1 != num){
          for(int i = 6; i < 0; i--){
            if(num1 < num){
              System.out.println("Sorry," + num1 + "is too low");
              System.out.println("You have" + i + "strikes left");
            }else{
              if(num1 > num){
                System.out.println("Sorry," + num1 + "is too high");
                System.out.println("You have" + i + "strikes left");
              }
            }
            if(num1 == num){
            System.out.println("Correct! The secret number was" + secretnum);
          }
        }
        if(num1 < 0 || num1 > 100){
          for(int i = 6; i < 0; i--){
          System.out.println("You were supposed to enter a number between 1 and 100");
          System.out.println("You have" + i + "strikes left");

          }
        }
      }
    }
    if(a1.equals("No"));
    System.out.println("Goodbye");
  }
   input.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know what toLowerCase method does?

Comment: Not really, I'm not experienced in this stuff at all, is that what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
String a1 = input.next().toLowerCase();
while(a1.equals("Yes")){
```

The first line turns *any* input into **lowercase** and stores the result of that operation to *a1*.

The second line checks if *a1* equals "Yes". Hint: a lowercase string can hardly ever be equal to "**Y**es"". That is the whole point of lowercasing your input up front!

The real answer here is: when you are not familiar with what such calls do, study their [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())!